# Transit in Dubai with two separate tickets - can SpiceJet boarding passes be collected airside?

Tags: transit, paperwork, dxb, emirates, spicejet

I'm a Indian citizen and currently don't have a UAE visa. I'm booked with Emirates from LHR To DXB and from DXB to IXM with SpiceJet with a transfer time of 2hrs 55min. The tickets are separate and I am travelling with hand luggage only.

I'm getting conflicting messages with respect to obtaining the boarding pass for my onward journey from Dubai to Madurai with SpiceJet. SpiceJet says I have to clear Immigration and check in only in their check-in counter. But Dubai Airport (via web chat) and Marhaba Services (on call) are saying I can get a boarding pass for any airline flying out of Dubai from Transfer Desk.

Am I sure to be able to obtain my boarding pass for my SpiceJet flight from the Transfer Desk, and has anyone experience of this?

Comment: Spicyjet just say "Passengers travelling on international flights originating from India need to get their travel documents etc. verified by the airline staff. Hence, after documents verified a fresh boarding card will be issued."

Comment: Hence you can check in online and print boarding card before Emirates flight.

Comment: Yes. I'm flying out of LHR

Comment: Thanks punts and Gagravarr for editing my question to make it more crisp and clear. So far I haven't got an answer to my question. So let me complete my trip and  update the details here so that it can help someone :)

Comment: thank you very much for the details. This is really helpful. Could you also let me know what if i have checked-in baggage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I received a boarding pass for spicejet at the transfer desk in Dubai without any issues.

Comment: Necro but trying my luck, but did you get a visa before boarding? And did Emirates cause any trouble when you were checking in at LHR?